# Screen rotation ice cream flashes

Tags: android

I have a service that run an activity when I want to lock an app , everything works well , but

when a locked app running , it shows lock screen well , but when I turn on Auto Rotation ON in device and rotate device , my activity load and and creates and stops and Destroy and again load , stop , destroy and this happens untill I kill activity .

where is my problem with Auto Rotation

I have this in manifest :

```
<activity
            android:name="activity_lockScreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="Lock Screen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

and this code to run activity at service

```
Intent lockIntent = new Intent(this, lockScreen.class);
    lockIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Log.d(tag, "new Run");
    startActivity(lockIntent);
```

my app works well on android 2.3 and 2.2 , but I got splash screen On android 4.0 , It seem that there is a problem with android 4 autorotation

Also called only once .

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well on some devices. I can't reproduce it myself.